# Create a Private Filesystem with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, model-view-controller, filesystems

I would like to know what to do in order to secure the files on my asp.net mvc application so that a user cannot crawl the file directory or download the file without a system generated link (so that I can check user permissions before giving the system generated link). Ideally the link would be different per user as well (or at-least something that a user won't be able to just guess the other links)

Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: They can't do it by default. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for that, still need the other part of this so that users can't download unless they get verified (even if they have the link).

Answer (score 0):

You need a document management system. 
You could write one in MVC of course :)

Store all the important stuff in that then provide links via a web site ... many use content management systems and document management systems together to provide a complete solution.

this results in a controlled "virtual" file system being made available based on permissions mappings between an authenticated user and the path to which they intend to gain access.